# Passing down arguments

Tags: options, pattern-matching, function-construction

In R, one can use `...` to pass arguments down to another function. For example

```r
fun <- function(arg1, ...){
  print(arg1)
  subfun(...)
}

subfun <- function(mex){
  print(mex)
}

fun(1, "passed down")
```

Is there a similar construct in *Mathematica*? In particular I would like to pass down the attribute `WorkingPrecision`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Are you looking for implementing [option handling](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OptionsPattern.html) by any chance?

Here's a small demonstration of implementing the `WorkingPrecision` option for function `fun`, giving it a default value, and always passing it down to `subfun`.

```
Options[fun] = {WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision}

(* ==> {WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision} *)

fun[arg1_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 subfun[arg1, WorkingPrecision -> OptionValue[WorkingPrecision]]

fun[1]

(* ==> subfun[1, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision] *)

fun[1, WorkingPrecision -> 10]

(* ==> subfun[1, WorkingPrecision -> 10] *)
```

If you need to pass down *every option*, then @Mr.Wizard's solution is the right one.  To restrict it to options only (expressions of the form `name -> value`), use

```
ClearAll[fun]
fun[arg_, opt: OptionsPattern[]] := subfun[arg, opt]

fun[1, WorkingPrecision -> 10, someOptions -> "value"]

(* ==> subfun[1, WorkingPrecision -> 10, someOptions -> "value"] *)
```

Comment: +1 for doing what I was too lazy to (until the OP clarifies the question).

Comment: @Szabolcs is there a way to pass all declared options of one function to a sub function without having to type it out? If you have three options, it already is quite verbose.

Comment: @SumNeuron `myPlot[arg_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Graphics[{Circle[]}, FilterRules[{opt}, Options[Graphics]]]`.  With some functions you may need to precede `FilterRule` with `Sequence @@`.

Comment: @Szabolcs just to clarify, will that pass down the default arguments or the set arguments as well?

Comment: @SumNeuron Only explicitly set arguments.  You want the default ones for `myPlot` (which may be different form the default for `Graphics`)?

Comment: @Szabolcs Both... If you have a function that calls a built in function with some non-default options (e.g. for plots) then I want to - without explicitly typing everything out - pass it the defaults of the encapsulating functions as well as those explicitly set

Comment: @SumNeuron Sounds like that would make a good question, if well written and well explained. To be honest, it's probably a duplicate, but I cannot find it now. Ping me here if you post the question.  In short, I would add `FilterRules[Options[myPlot], Options[Graphics]]` at the end of the example above.  It exploits the fact that options specified first take precedence.

Comment: @Szabolcs question posted :) http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/inheriting-options

Answer (score 15):

Here is what I see written, translated as literally as possible:

```
fun[arg1_, args___] := (
  Print[arg1];
  subfun[args]
)

subfun[mex_] := (
  Print[mex]
)

fun[1, "passed down"]
```

> 1
>
> passed down

Comment: Beat me to it by a minute, pretty much posting the identical answer! http://imgur.com/qpy9k

Comment: Your answer addresses exactly my question, I take it it was enough clear. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 13):

Both the previous examples are perfect if you know explicitly what option you want to pass.

In the more general case you may want to give none, one, or several of a compound set of options to more than one function chosen from a predefined set of functions.

You may even want to give a function as an argument , or option, to a function which can then utilise options given in the primary function call.

Hopefully the example below shows how to do this for built in and user defined functions, it makes use of `OptionValue` to access option values and `FilterRules` to ensure that only valid options are passed to any function.

```
Clear[f, ff, fff];

(* ff, a function to do something, with a parameter *)
Options[ff] = {Squared -> False};
ff[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := If[OptionValue@Squared, x x, x];

(* fff, another function to do something, with a different parameter *)
Options[fff] = {Cubed -> False};
fff[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := If[OptionValue@Cubed, x x x, x];

(* A set of functions you would like your function to be able to handle options for *)
myFuncs = {ff, fff, Plot};

(* Gather together the options from the set of functions you want your function to support, 
plus the options for your own function itself  *)
Options[f] = 
  Flatten[{Flatten[Options /@ myFuncs, 1], myOpt1 -> 7, 
    aFunction -> ff}, 1];


(* f,  a function which has it's own options and can accept an arbitrary function 
and associated options from the set of those functions who's options it 
supports and returns some elements based on those options *)
f[p1_, func_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{p, q, r},

  (* Utilise the function's own, explicitly defined option, myOpt1 and calls a function, 
which was passed as a parameter, along with it's valid options. 
This is achieved using FilterRules  *)
  p = OptionValue[myOpt1] func[p1, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[func]]];

  (* Call a function, passed as an option and any associted options it may 
  have which were passed into this function *)
  q = OptionValue[aFunction][p1, 
    FilterRules[{opts}, Options[OptionValue[aFunction]]]];

  (* Call Plot and filter any options given to this function which are supported by plot *)
  r = Plot[
    ff[x, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[OptionValue[aFunction]]]], {x, 
     0, 10}, Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]] ;

 (* return the computed elements *)
  {p, q, r}
  ]
(* An example function call, with options for ff, fff and Plot  *)

f[5, fff, Frame -> True, Squared -> True, Cubed -> True]
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I can't disagree, but I went with the spirit of the posts above, with a light style of commentary. But I thought it perhaps added a greater depth to the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the code comments. +1

Comment: This is VERY helpful!