# Manipulating OptionsPatterns[]

Tags: plotting, function-construction, options

How do you combine `OptionsPatterns`?

For example, I would like to have a function that can take both options that I specify, and options for all graphs:

```
Options[f]={"a"->b} + OptionsPattern[LogPlot]
f[...,OptionsPattern[]] := LogPlot[..., ImageSize->OptionsValue[ImageSize]]
```

A related question, how do I remove options from an `OptionsPattern`, and pass on the remainder to another function.

For example:

```
f[...,OptionsPattern[LogPlot]] := LogPlot[..., (* pass on all the options EXCEPT Frame *)]
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: A somewhat related [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1901/524) with very good answers

Comment: @Ryogi:  Thanks! That has a great answer for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This information is given in the tutorial [Setting Up Functions with Optional Arguments](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments.html). Just catch the options given to your function in a variable and use `FilterRules`

```
odeplot[de_, y_, {x_, x0_, x1_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{sol},
  sol = NDSolve[de, y, {x, x0, x1}, 
    FilterRules[{opts}, Options[NDSolve]]];
  If[Head[sol] === NDSolve,
   $Failed,
   Plot[Evaluate[y /. sol], {x, x0, x1}, 
    Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]]]
   ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 12):

For your "related question", of passing all options to `LogPlot` other than `Frame`, just set the option to the value you want, and place this first in the function call. The first occurrence of the option is used, so any use of it in `opts` is redundant and ignored.

```
f[data_, opts:OptionsPattern[]]:= LogPlot[data, Frame->False, 
  Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts},Options[LogPlot]]] ]
```