# Inheriting Options?

Tags: function-construction, options

This question is an extension of [Passing down arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1901/passing-down-arguments/1907?noredirect=1#comment380487_1907).

To help clarify my question, I will be referring to another recent post of mine [Making Quartile Plots from a Dataset](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140760/making-quartile-plots-from-a-dataset), the code to which can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/Wolfram-Binned-Quartile-Plot/tree/master).

## Context

It is clear that arguments can be passed down as demonstrated in both the documentation and in [`@Szabolcs`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1907/42578) to [Passing down arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1901/passing-down-arguments/1907?noredirect=1#comment380487_1907) by using `passedToOption -> OptionValue[<option>]`.

Although verbose it works fine when one needs to only pass one or two options. However this convention is too verbose and cluttering to write clear code when one must pass a *lot* of options.

Consider Mathematica's many `Plot` functions and the numerous options available. While the defaults are nice, if one is making a custom plotting function, such as in [Making Quartile Plots from a Dataset](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140761/42578), one may prefer different options those chosen by Wolfram. Further, to maintain the flexibility of the original `Plot` function, all the options must be defined in the `Options` of the function - Wolfram's defaults and my own.

In the linked code above, one can see why this would be useful, especially for the `BinnedQuartilePlot` and the host of color functions that pass their options down several functions.

## Question

Is there a concise way to pass, from one function to another, all Options of the encapsulating function - both the defaults and those explicitly set?

## Code

```
f[x_] := x^2
Options[myPlot] := {"PlotRange" -> Full, "PlotStyle" -> "Pastel", "Filling" -> "Axis"}
myPlot[function_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Plot[function[x], {x, 1, 5},
  PlotRange -> OptionValue["PlotRange"],
  PlotStyle -> OptionValue["PlotStyle"],
  Filling -> OptionValue["Filling"]]
```

Comment: related: [Clean and handy Options management/filtering](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82626/5478)

Comment: @Kuba I'll check that out. Added some code :)

Comment: Why not do something like `myPlot[function_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Plot[function[x], {x, 1, 5}, Evaluate @ FilterRules[{opts} ~Join~ Options[myPlot], Options[Plot]]]`?

Comment: That should really be `PlotRange`, not `"PlotRange"`.  Generally, string and symbol versions should be interchangeable when used in option handling functions.  But if you (or the author or some other function) accidentally uses some other functions to manipulate options (like @MB1965 did with `DeleteDuplicatesBy`, see my comment), then there may be a mixup.

Comment: @Szabolcs thank you for the tip and warning. I do not use Mathematica options with strings in my own functions - generally.  I just typed this into S.E. and out of habit added the quotes. Much appreciated for the forewarning though.

Comment: I mean, if an option name exists as a symbol, better to use it as a symbol.  When introducing a new name, feel free to use a string. I usually use a string to avoid creating too many symbols.

Comment: @J.M. that looks nice! Where did you learn that?

Comment: @Sum, it's the modern form of a pattern I've been using for years, back when *Mathematica* had the (package) function `FilterOptions[]` instead of the modern `FilterRules[]`.

Comment: Also related: [(353)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/353/121), [(3247)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3247/121)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let us assume that you are designing a function which can take its own unique options, but also shares option names with `Plot`.  What is the best way to implement such a function `myPlot`?  Below I will try to give a complete guide on how to do this.

There are two common approaches:

1. The default values for `Plot`-specific options will be taken directly from `Plot`.  Changing `Plot` options with `SetOptions` also affects `myPlot`.  It is not possible to use `SetOptions` *on `myPlot`* with `Plot`-specific options. This is only possible with options unique to `myPlot`.
2. `myPlot` has its own copy of `Plot`'s options.  Changing `Plot`'s options does not affect `myPlot`.  Any of these options can be changed directly on `myPlot` using `SetOptions`.

Most builtin functions use approach (2).

For the following, it is good to be aware that when an option is specified multiple times, Mathematica always takes the first value.

#### Inheriting defaults from `Plot`

Here's how to implement approach (1).  We start by setting the defaults of `myPlot`'s unique options:

```
Options[myPlot] = { Top -> 10 };

myPlot[f_, opt : OptionsPattern[{myPlot, Plot}]] := 
  Plot[f[x], {x, 0, OptionValue[Top]}, 
    Evaluate@FilterRules[{opt}, Options[Plot]]
  ]
```

Here, the purpose of specifying `Plot` within `OptionsPattern` was to avoid error messages when using options that are present in `Options[Plot]` but not in `Options[myPlot]`.

An additional effect is that now you can use `OptionValue` with `Plot`-specific options.  We do not need this in this specific implementation.  However, specifying `Plot` within `OptionsPattern` is still necessary to avoid errors.

Using `Evaluate` before `FilterRule` was necessary because `Plot` is `HoldAll`.

If you put this function in a package, at some point you may want to add syntax information to it.  Like this:

```
SyntaxInformation[myPlot] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, OptionsPattern[]}}
```

But now we run into a problem.  `Plot`-specific options *work*, but they are coloured in red, as if they were incorrect.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The workaround is using an undocumented entry in `SyntaxInformation`, `"OptionNames"`:

```
SyntaxInformation[
   myPlot] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, OptionsPattern[]}, 
   "OptionNames" -> Union[First /@ Options[myPlot], First /@ Options[Plot]]};
```

#### Separate defaults for `myPlot` and `Plot`

This is the more common approach, and this is what builtins use.

We start by setting `myPlot`'s unique options, as well as copying over `Plot`'s options.  Here, we do not change `Plot`'s defaults.

```
Options[myPlot] = Join[
   {Top -> 10}
   Options[Plot]
  ];
```

Now we are ready to change some `Plot`-specific options from their default values:

```
SetOptions[myPlot, {PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red}];
```

Now we can define `myPlot`:

```
myPlot[f_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, OptionValue[Top]}, 
    Evaluate@FilterRules[Join[{opt}, Options[myPlot]], Options[Plot]]
 ]
```

We no longer need to list function names in `OptionsPattern[]`.  But now we need to pass down all options, as set either in `opt` or in `Options[myPlot]` to the `Plot` function.  We can simply `Join` all of them together, relying on the fact that when duplicates are present, the value will be taken from the first occurrence.

Now the SyntaxInformation can be simpler:

```
SyntaxInformation[myPlot] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, OptionsPattern[]}}
```

The allowed option names will be taken from `Options[myPlot]`.

---

Finally, you can also mix these two approaches.  You can have only a subset of `Plot`'s options present in `Options[myPlot]`.  I do not recommend that you do this because it can be confusing to users.  Either put all of them in there (the more common approach), or none of them at all.

Comment: Can I ask a few newbie questions? what is `opt : OptionsPattern[]` syntax? What about about `FilterRules` in general?

Comment: `opt` is the pattern name.  `x : _` is exactly the same thing as `x_` (see its `FullForm`).  When the pattern is something else than `_`, you need `:` to give it a name.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Where did you learn that?

Comment: @SumNeuron I would tell you that everything is [in the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Patterns.html).  But inexplicably, in version 11.1 some essential tutorial links were removed from that page. If you still use 11.0, you will find them at the top. Otherwise look here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsOverview.html

Comment: I noticed that (removal of links) as well. I just haven't seen `:` used before.

Comment: @SumNeuron A good place to learn is still what is called the [*Virtual Book*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VirtualBookOverview.html) which links the more explicit tutorials that Szabolcs has mentioned. I have linked it for easier reference.

Comment: @SumNeuron Yes, before version 6, the documentation had an actual table of contents.  In 6, that was removed, and we are expected to just search instead.  It was the trend at that time: there's too much information for traditional organization, so let's use search instead, or sloppy "tagging", etc. The problem is that sometimes you do not know what to search for. If you don't know that there is `:`, you won't search for it.  People were upset, and by popular demand a limited table of contents was added. It was called the Virtual Book and it had a toolbar button.

Comment: However, it was not very well done, and (I assume) it didn't get that much use from new users.  So it got removed from the toolbar in version 10.0.  Now there's the page that gwr linked to, but you can't have a full overview of the ToC, you have to keep clicking on entries to see the sub-sections.  So it is not very usable.  It is also absolutely not discoverable.

Comment: @Szabolcs I tried running this and the plot doesn't render for (Separate defaults for myPlot and Plot).

Comment: @Szabolcs I think one the disadvantage of `Join` approach is that, if you join custom function options. It will make the order of function definition matters

Comment: @SumNeuron lol @ "Where did you learn that?" im sure you were a noob when you asked that about 5 years ago but now as an experienced journeyman in wolfam you likely learned that nearly everything is learned sitting many long hour behind a pc often doing nothing but studying the documentation and finding that after all that you didnt learn much after all. at least that is how it was for me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define functions `f` and `g` such that `f` calls `g`, and `f` passes its option values down to `g`.

We must assume that `f` and `g` can take the same options

```
ClearAll[f]; ClearAll[g];

Options[f] = {"a" -> True, "b" -> True};
Options[g] = Options[f];
```

To pass the options from `f` to `g` (defaults unless explicit options are provided, and explicit values otherwise) we construct a list of the options values for `f` at runtime using `Thread[Rule @@ {#, OptionValue[f, #]}] &@Keys[Options[f]]`, like so:

```
f[OptionsPattern[]] := With[
  {(*The solution is this bit here:*)
   opts = Thread[Rule @@ {#, OptionValue[f, #]}] &@Keys[Options[f]]},
  g[opts]]

g[OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue@Keys[Options[g]]
```

Now calling `f` with options `"a"->"False"` and `"b"->"False"}` passes the options to `g` and returns the expected result:

```
in[]: f["a" -> "False", "b" -> False]

out[]: {False,False}
```

I hope this helps!