# OptionValue: unknown option

Tags: options

I found sometimes, I need both `OptionValue` to get a customized default value and `FilterRules` in a function.

Below is an illustration of the problem

```
Options[myPlot] = {cc -> 10};
myPlot[f_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{},
  Plot[f[x] OptionValue[cc], {x, 1, 2}, 
   Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]], PlotRange -> All]
  ]
```

If I run `myPlot[Sin, ImageSize -> 600]`, though the result is fine. However, it will warns me

> OptionValue::nodef: Unknown option ImageSize for myPlot.

`Trace` shows the problems is when executing `OptionValue[myPlot, {ImageSize -> 600}, cc]` internally. I can't figure out a way to get rid of this warning message instead of using `Quiet`. So I am asking here if I am using `OptionValue` the wrong way?

Comment: Try `myPlot[f_, opts : OptionsPattern[{myPlot, Plot}]] := (* stuff *)`.

Comment: @J.M. Great, works, Thank you so much! +1

Comment: I prefer using `Options[myPlot] = Join[Options[Plot], {cc -> 10}]` so that I see all possible options listed when I use `Options[myPlot]`.

Comment: Hi, @CarlWoll Your approach is subtly different from J.M.  If you want some customized default `Plot` option for example `PlotRange -> {0, 10}`. Then you can only put them in `Join[{PlotRange -> {0, 10}}, Options[Plot], {cc -> 10}]` right before `Options[Plot]`. However, in J.M. solution, we can put it inside `Plot`, but have to be sure it is after `Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]]`

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140912/12