# What is the best way to pass on options?

Tags: function-construction, options, optional-arguments

Say I have two functions which take the same set of options, e.g.

```
Options[f1] = {a -> 1};
Options[f2] = {a -> 1};
```

Now, `f1` calls `f2` and passes its options on, like this:

```
f1[options:OptionsPattern[]] := f2[options]
```

Where `f2` may be

```
f2[options:OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue[a]
```

Usually ,this works fine:

```
f1[]
(* 1 *)

f1[a -> 2]
(* 2 *)
```

But `SetOptions` does not behave the way I want it to:

```
SetOptions[f1, a -> 2];
f1[]
(* 1 *)
```

I understand that this does not work because `options` is empty, and `f2` never asks for the `Options` of `f1`. One way to solve this is to define

```
f2[options:OptionsPattern[]] :=  If[
  Length[{options}] > 0, 
  OptionValue[a], 
  OptionValue[f1, a]
]
```

Now, after `SetOptions[f1, a -> 2]`

```
f1[]
(* 2 *)

f1[a -> 3]
(* 3 *)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/inheriting-options)